# Where is XAMPP's Shell?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, lamp

I am using the latest version of XAMPP with XAMPP control panel v2.5 (9 May 2007). I want to access the command line to run `php -q htdocs\path\to\file.php`.

**Problem:** On my XAMPP control panel, I do not see the `Shell` button that will bring up the command line interface. How can I access the shell, or is there another way to run the PHP file?

**My XAMPP Control Panel**

[image]

**What I am finding:**
[image]

Comment: Why don't you open the console, change the directory to `C:\xampp\php` and execute `php.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `php.exe`'s directory in your `PATH` environment variable, you can simply open a command line window (Start > Run > cmd), go in your PHP script directory and launch it with `php yourscript.php`.

Answer (score 2):

If You need to access XAMPP shell to run i.e pear command You need to go to XAMPP installation directory and run xampp-control-3-beta.exe (XAMPP version 1.7.7). After clicking xampp shell button it prompt pops up asking if You want to create shell.bat say Yes and You are good to go.

Comment: Why not simply use `c:\xampp\php\php.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

In my windows box, xampp shell is just a instance of cmd.exe running a batch file

[image]