# How to import a DB that weighs 166MB into MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working in developer mode and try to import the DB with the importer that delivers me phpmyadmin both with the .sql script and with a .zip file and always generates an error, for example in the zip file I get an error when inserting x table that contains more than 90k of data.

I'm currently working with Xampp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xampp - PHPMyAdmin upload large files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343863/xampp-phpmyadmin-upload-large-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember when I could benchpress 166MB no problem...

The easiest solution is probably just to use a [command line import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666249/how-do-i-import-an-sql-file-using-the-command-line-in-mysql)...  Something like `mysql -u username -p database_name < file_name.sql`  It may take a while to do its thing though.  You can also try some of the answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343863/xampp-phpmyadmin-upload-large-files/22655453).